# How to display data from two master and child table based upon a condition

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two tables Category(Master),Products(child). I want to combine them and get some data and display it

```
 public partial class Product
{
    public int Product_Id { get; set; }       
    public string Product_Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Regular_Price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Category_Id { get; set; }
}
public partial class Category
{
    public int Category_Id { get; set; }
    public string Category_Name { get; set; }
}
//A viewmodel as
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Product { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the data as

```
Product_Id   Product_Name   Price   Category_Id
1            a1             5000    10
2            a2             5700    10
3            a3             5000    10
4            a4             5000    10
5            b1             1000    20
6            b2             2000    20
7            c1             4000    30
8            c2             7000    30

Category_Id   Category_Name
10            A            
20            B            
30            C            
40            D
```

Here my requirement is I want something like

```
@foreach(var item in model
 {
   //Required code
 }
A
a1 
a2
a3
a4
B
b1
b2
C
c1
c2
```

Is the ViewModel proper or do I require changes in it.
Thanks

Comment: Looks like you want to display all categories, so the model would need to be `@model IEnumerable<ViewModel>` and you would need 2 `foreach` loops - an outer one for each Category, and an inner one for each Product of the Category

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you please elaborate

Comment: Was my assumption correct (are you wanting to display all categories with a sub list of its products)? - not sure what you need to know?

Comment: @StephenMuecke exactly that was what I were looking after. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your output(what you have shown) your `ViewModel` should like:-

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> ProductName { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName{ get; set; }
    }
```

Since You are intrested in `CategoryName` & its respective `ProductName`, You can use `group join` like this:-

```
List<ViewModel> result = (from c in category
                                      join p in products
                                      on c.Category_Id equals p.Category_Id into g
                                      select new ViewModel
                                      {
                                          CategoryName = c.Category_Name,
                                          ProductName = g.Select(x => x.Product_Name)
                                      }).ToList();
```

If you want to fetch complete `Product` object then simply change your ViewModel like this:-

```
public class ViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Product> Product { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
```

And select the complete Product from query:-

```
//Rest of the query
select new ViewModel
        {
             CategoryName = c.Category_Name,
             Product = g
        }).ToList();
```

In your View you can use `foreach` loop to show the results, here is the complete [Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H8wRND).

Comment: and how about accessing within view. Thanks

Comment: @User - You can use nested `foreach` loop in view, refer to the Fiddle I have added.

Comment: @User - Did you get a chance to look at my answer?

Comment: Thanks for your ans I got it and your fiddler  helped me  plus I made some edits as per my requirements. Well Thanks again for your fiddler and answer as well +1.